# Can't create handler inside threads that has not called looper?

Tags: java, android

I want to send a notification after 5 seconds.

I found this code example to do something after **5 seconds**, but I just can set a `Log.e()`.
The `Notification` method is also working. But if I want to call the method `setNotification()`, I get a `RuntimeError` after **5 seconds**:

> Can't create Handler inside Thread that has not called looper.prepare().

I found very much help, but nothing works.   So I hope you can help me.

```
public class Reminder {
    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() { 
        todo_list rem = new todo_list();
        rem.setNotification("Todo!", false, 1);
    }
}

public class todo_list extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new Reminder(5);
    }

    public void setNotification(String text, boolean ongoing, int id) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call rem.setNotification from a thread which will keep running always.  One way is to use [runonuithread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

```
runonUithread(new Runnable(){
    run(){
        rem.setNotification("Todo!",false,1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error when you execute some code that shouldn't be done in another thread than the UI thread. So simple get an activity object and call `runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {}` on it. Place that code that generates the error in the `Runnable`.

I hope this helps.